# Using UISwipeGestureRecognizer and drawing code

Tags: iphone, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I need a control that allows user to

1) draw on it

2) swipe to go to next screen (through an event or a delegate)

I've tried to add UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the view but it didn't work the way I wanted. My UI setup is like this:

Main Controller:

- view  (with UISwipeGestureRecognizer)

  - subview (owned by another controller that captures touch events and draws the graphics)

Whenever I try to draw a horizontal line on the canvas, the UISwipeGestureRecognizer takes over and fires the "go to next screen" event.

How can I prevent UISwipeGestureRecognizer from doing that? I am thinking about differentiating horizontal line vs swipe based on the duration/length but UISwipeGestureRecognizer does not support anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a pretty confusing user experience, but if you're determined to do this, you'll probably need to subclass `UIGestureRecognizer` and tune it to recognize exactly the type of swipes you care about.